# $\frac{a(a+b)}{4a^2+ab+b^2} + \frac{b(b+c)}{4b^2+bc+c^2} + \frac{c(c+a)}{4c^2+ca+a^2} \leq 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, fractions

I've got stuck at this problem:

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be real numbers. Prove that
>   $$\frac{a(a+b)}{4a^2+ab+b^2} + \frac{b(b+c)}{4b^2+bc+c^2} + \frac{c(c+a)}{4c^2+ca+a^2} \leq 1$$

Firstly, I've thought this :
$$a^2 - 2ab + b^2 \geq 0$$
$$4a^2 + ab + b^2 \geq 3(ab + a^2)$$
$$\frac{a(a+b)}{4a^2 + ab + b^2} \leq \frac{1}{3}$$
Similarly we obtain that

$$\frac{b(b+c)}{4b^2+bc+c^2} \leq \frac{1}{3}$$
And 
$$\frac{c(c+a)}{4c^2+ca+a^2} \leq \frac{1}{3}$$
Summing all, we obtain the inequality.

Is this way correct?
(I have doubts about my solution because this problem was found in a math magazine which usually has difficult problems(at least for me)). Or is there a another way?

Thanks!

Comment: You are dividing by $4a^2+ab+b^2$.  Are you sure this is positive?

Comment: Well solved.... +1 :-)

Comment: @vadim123: If $t = \frac a b$, isn't $b^2 (4t^2 + t + 1)$ strictly positive?

Comment: @vadim123 Yes, of course, since $\frac12(a+b)^2+\frac72a^2+\frac12b^2$ is the sum of squares which is positive. Also, $a^2+b^2 \geq 2|ab|$.

Comment: @vadim123  $\frac{8a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2}{2}$ or $\frac{7a^2 + (a+b)^2 + b^2}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is equivalent to:
$$
\sum_{cyc}\frac{3a(a+b)}{4a^2+ab+b^2}≤3\iff \\
0≤\sum_{cyc}1-\frac{3a(a+b)}{4a^2+ab+b^2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2-2ab+b^2}{4a^2+ab+b^2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2}{(a-b)^2+3a(a+b)}\iff\\
0≤\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2}{\left(\frac{7}{4}a-\frac{1}{4}b\right)^2+\frac{15}{16}(a+b)^2}
$$
Which is obvious.